# In Rails, how can I force a converstion from a String to an object when my form is submitted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, type-conversion, form-submit, belongs-to

I’m using Rails 4.2.4.  I have a table “my_objects” with a column “address_id” that is a foreign key back to my “addresses” table.  So in my my_object.rb model, I had to create a method for saving the object and the address at the same time

```
  belongs_to :address, :autosave => true, dependent: :destroy
  def save_with_address
    transaction do
      if !self.address.nil?
        address = Address.new(self.address)
        address.my_object = self
        address.save
        self.address = address
      end

      # Save the object
      save
    end
  end
```

For reference, my address object (which has a state_id column dn country_id column in the database) is structured like so …

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :country
  has_one :my_object
end
```

However, when I submit my form, with the below data

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "my_object"=>{"id"=>"", "name"=>"Dave20", "day"=>"07/06/2016", "distance"=>"10", "distance_unit_id"=>"5", "hour"=>"00", "minute"=>"04", "second"=>"05", "address"=>{"city"=>"baltimore", "state"=>"3555"}, "my_object_times_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"overall_rank"=>"", "age_group_rank"=>"", "gender_rank"=>"", "time_in_ms"=>"245000"}}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
```

this line, “address = Address.new(self.address)” is failing with the error, “ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (State(#70161141072220) expected, got String(#70161059455060)):”.  Evidently Rails isn’t converting my state ID string into an object.  How can I make it do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Address` model is dependent on another two models `State` and `country`, So when you tried to create new object for `Address` by passing the `self.address` it's raise the error.

To resolve this issue you have to make changes in your code by creatting new object for `state` and `country` by passed value and pass this objec to `Address.new`, right now `state` and `country` pass as a `string`, so obviouly it will not going to work

Hope this will help.

Comment: Is there any way I can change the names of the parameters so that the conversion will automatically happen?  If that is impossible, then could you give examples regarding your comment, "make changes in your code by creatting new object"?

Comment: You have to provide that `state` and `country` field drop down in your form and pass the value as `state_id` and `country_id` for your `address` model.

Answer (score 1):

Use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) method. For more detailed explanation [see](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms).